# Co-existence of Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3 and 10.4 on the same computer

Tags: c++builder, coexistence

Does anyone have experience with both versions (C++Builder 10.3 and 10.4) installed on the same computer?  Are there possible issues?

Only EhLib is used as an additional component. We want to be sure that old projects will still work with the 10.3 version.

Comment: There is no way to be sure other than to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple *major* releases of the IDE can co-exist on the same machine just fine, as long as they are installed in different folders, which they are by default.

10.3 and 10.4 are *major* version releases, so they will co-exist together on the same machine.

That being said...

> We want to be sure that old projects will still work with the 10.3 version.

You cannot upgrade an old project to a newer IDE and then continue using the same project in the older IDE.  You will need separate projects for each IDE, though they can share source code files.

However, you cannot share components between IDE versions, as the binaries are specific to the compiler version that created them.  So, you will have to install EhLib into each IDE version separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install different C++ Builder versions on the same computer. I have C++ Builder XE2, C++ Builder 10.2, C++ Builder 10.3 and C++ Builder 10.4 on the same computer. Install each version in a separate folder.